# Merging two maps with same key in java

Tags: java

I have a given map as follows:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> data1;
data1 = {'xxx':{'x':{'abc':'xyz'}}};
```

I want to add data2 in it:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> data2;
data2 = {'xxx':{'y':{'cde':'xyz'},'z':{'cde':'xyz'}};
```

The data1 should be changed to:

```
data1 = {'xxx':{'x':{'abc':'xyz'},'y':{'cde':'xyz'},'z':{'cde':'xyz'}}
```

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Does the 3rd level map need to merge?

Comment: Is `xxx` in that example meant to be an integer?

Comment: There's almost certainly something wrong if you have a three-level map in your design.

Comment: OOP does not embracing this kind of solutions...

Comment: @zlakad Why not?

Comment: I don't need three level merging.

Comment: @YassinHajaj In most cases it suggests that designer should use specific class instead of array/map. For instance would you rather work with collection of Persons where you have accessors for age/name/etc, or collection of maps holding some key/values? Nested collections usually can be rewritten into more readable/maintainable code.

Comment: @berry120 yes..

Comment: @YassinHajaj, IMHO, there must be a better way to solve a problem without using the n-th dimensional collections... I mean in most of the cases...

Answer (score 0):

Using nested loops, you should be able to do the following

```
for (Map.Entry entry : data1.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry entry2 : data2.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().equals(entry2.getKey())) {
            Map<String, Map<String, Object>> value = entry.getValue();
            value.putAll(entry2.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Using **[Map#computeIfPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)**

```
for (Map.Entry entry : data2.entrySet()) {
    data1.computeIfPresent(entry.getKey(), (k,v) -> v.putAll(entry.getValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to merge the first level map, then try this:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> r =
                Stream.of(data1.entrySet(), data2.entrySet())
                      .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Create stream of all entry 
                      .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, // Group by Entry::getKey which is your Integer
                                          mapping(Entry::getValue,  // Get Value from your entry
                                                  reducing(new HashMap<>(),
                                                           (m1, m2) -> {
                                                               m1.putAll(m2);
                                                               return m1;
                                                           }
                                                  ))));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code supports merging two levels down

```
data2.forEach((k, v) -> data1.merge(k, v, (original, newMap) -> {
    newMap.forEach((k1,v1) -> original.merge(k1, v1, (innerMap, newInnerMap) -> {
        newInnerMap.forEach((k2,v2) -> innerMap.put(k2,v2));
        return innerMap;
    }));
    return original;
}));
```